# .htaccess to hide extension for both html and php files

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I'm working on some PHP pages for a client and I run into a problem.

He likes links for his website to be http://www.website.com/about (without the extension). In his .htaccess is this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

</IfModule>
```

Now, the pages i'm making are having extension of php and there is my problem. I have tried several different variations of .htaccess and nothing seems to work. If there is contact.html the URL will be /contact, but if i rename that contact.html page to contact.php and i open /contact page again it is showing me 404 page.

I tried several .htaccess and they are:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.((html)|(php))$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.([^.]+)$  $1 [R,L]
```

another one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

</IfModule>
```

I tried more, but they are all gone now. Basically, nothing is working and I don't know what the problem is.

Any help would be awesome...

Comment: "Not working" isn't a sufficient problem description. IfModule has no place in htaccess files. Provide a full URL request example. And don't come back without a RewriteLog!!!

Comment: I don't have access to cPanel, just the FTP. I thought maybe the mistake is on my site and .htaccess file. I will provide RewriteLog tomorrow when the client wakes up. www.website.com/contact.html - works, www.website.com/contact.php - works, www.website.com/contact (that have only html contact on server) - works, www.website.com/contact (that have only php contact on server) - doesn't work. I need that last one to work.

Comment: So `contact.php` and `contact.html` exist? And you're wondering why the RewriteRule doesn't know which to match for `http://example.com/contact`? Well, how is it supposed to map two things at the same time?

Comment: No. When contact.html exists rewrite is working, when only contact.php works it is not working. I have now both files contact.html and contact1.php. When i open webpage www.website.com/contact it opens the html page normally, if i go on www.website.com/contact1 it shows 404...